# Efficiently append and update rows in delta table

Tags: database, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I'm working with Azure databricks and needs to append and update records in a delta table.

Since I'm quite new to Spark (and Databricks for that matter) my main question is if Im on the right track here..

So to the matter at hand:

1. I have one delta table (source table) that contains information about files (e.g. filepath).
2. I run three parallel processes that filter out rows from the source table, use the filepath to load the file and extract data from it (the files are stored in a blob storage). fyi: each process will handle different file-extensions.
3. Once a process have extracted data from a file I would like to write the results into another table (result table).
4. When all three processes have finished: Multiple processes should spin up and start analyse the the data that were written into the result table.
5. The analyze result should then be written/updated into the same row as the data are stored in the result table.

**So for the first case of appending extracte data to the result table (step 2):**
Should I just make use of the normal "write" function e.g.

```
spark.createDataFrame([file_data_dict]).write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(table_path)
```

the goal is to append one new row

Or

Should I go towards structured streaming and if so, why?
I've tried some with the `writeStream` but either am I using it wrong or this is the wrong use case. Because I see no improvment regarding time. My code:

```
# Start stream
strmdf = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(stream_path)
q = strmdf.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", f"{stream_path}/_checkpoint").start(stream_path)

# Save into stream
spark.createDataFrame([data_dict]).write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(stream_path)
```

Another thing I've been looking into is to use `UDF` or `forEach` together with the stream but have not succeeded fully there yet.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the PySpark to process a list of files in parallel.
As an example to process files of different formats, including **TXT**, **CSV**, and ***JSON***.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import concurrent.futures
def process_txt(row):
    if row["filename"].endswith(".txt"):
        return f"Processing TXT file: {row['filepath']}"
def process_csv(row):
    if row["filename"].endswith(".csv"):
        return f"Processing CSV file: {row['filepath']}"
def process_json(row):
    if row["filename"].endswith(".json"):
        return f"Processing JSON file: {row['filepath']}"
data = [
    ("Hello_world___.txt", "/FileStore/tables/Hello_world___.txt"),
    ("example.csv", "/FileStore/tables/example.csv"),
    ("jsonexample.json", "/FileStore/tables/jsonexample.json")
]
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("parallel-processing") \
    .config("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["filename", "filepath"])
def process_partition(iterator):
    results = []
    for row in iterator:
        if row["filename"].endswith(".txt"):
            results.append(process_txt(row))
        elif row["filename"].endswith(".csv"):
            results.append(process_csv(row))
        elif row["filename"].endswith(".json"):
            results.append(process_json(row))
    return results
results = df.rdd.mapPartitions(process_partition).collect()
result_df = spark.createDataFrame([(result,) for result in results], ["result"])
result_df.write.mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").saveAsTable("result_table")
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

[image]

constructs a DataFrame from a list of file data, and defines a function to process the DataFrame in parallel. Finally, it writes the processed results to a Spark SQL table.

- In the code I am importing `Libariries` from the `pyspark.sql` module and `concurrent.futures` for parallel processing.
- `process_txt`, `process_csv`, and `process_json`, are defined to process files with TXT, CSV, and JSON formats
- A list named `data` that contains tuples of file names and file paths, representing different file formats
- Defining a function named `process_partition` that processes each partition in parallel.
  It checks the file extension and applies the appropriate processing function based on the file format.
- Using the `mapPartitions` method on the DataFrame's RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) to apply the `process_partition` function to each partition in parallel.
- New DataFrame named `result_df` from the processed results.
- The code writes the `result_df` DataFrame to a Spark SQL table named "result_table" using the `saveAsTable` method.
  The `mode` and `option` methods are used to specify the write mode and schema merging options.

Using the above process leverage the parallel processing capabilities of Apache Spark to process different file formats in a distributed and scalable manner.

**To Append data to Delta table:**

```
analyzed_data.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("append").save(table_path)
```

**Save the analyzed data as a Delta table:**

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true")
analyzed_data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("result_table")
```

Comment: this is very inefficient way of updating table

Comment: I have tried the like this
spark.sql(f"UPDATE result_table SET analyzed_result = '{analyzed_result}' WHERE _id = {row_id}")

Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @AlexOtt Could you please elaborate? And if you have the time, provide a more efficient way?